# gtk3+ and python rgba convert to hex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygtk, gtk3

i using gtk3 i found that it use rgba for representing color, but the **(red,green,blue,alpha)** are not integer between **0-255** but floating point number between **0-1.0**, so i don't know how to convert from rgba to hex and vice-versa

i have tried this code but its seem to not work :

```
def convert_to_hex(rgba_color) :
red = str(hex(int(rgba_color.red*255)))[2:].capitalize()
green = str(hex(int(rgba_color.green*255)))[2:].capitalize()
blue = str(hex(int(rgba_color.blue*255)))[2:].capitalize()

return '0x' + red + green + blue
```

Comment: "its seem to not work" - could you add more information? Do you get errors (provide full traceback)? Do you get unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: i receive a good hex number, but when i try the hex color online, it give me another color

Comment: Then please provide example inputs and outputs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the problem is that the number should have leading zeros when they are only 1 digit. Here is a solution for that.

```
def convert_to_hex(rgba_color) :
    red = int(rgba_color.red*255)
    green = int(rgba_color.green*255)
    blue = int(rgba_color.blue*255)
    return '0x{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}'.format(r=red,g=green,b=blue)
```

Comment: its still not working, its give me a hex number, but when i try the hex online it give another color