# Apply color to specific node networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to color the nodes in my graph by the value of a node attribute, and for a specific value of an attribute, I would like to apply a gradient. This is different from the (many!) other responses that I have seen, that aim to add color to a node from a `matplotlib` cmap (e.g. `cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greens')`) for all the nodes in a graph. I would like to apply one color to one type of node, and a color map to another type of node.

Here is what I have tried so far. I think this is failing because I'm trying to add a string (e.g. 'yellow') and rgba values (e.g. `cmap(dict_1[node])`) to `color_map`, which I then use for the `node_color` parameter of `nx.draw()`.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

color_map = []
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greens')

for node in g:
    if node in list_1:
        color_map.append('yellow')
    elif node in list_2:
        rgba = cmap(dict_1[node])
        color_map.append(rgba*-1)

nx.draw(g, node_color = color_map, node_size = 75)
```

The `color_map` method works just fine when I only add colors by name to the `color_map`, but not in the current form.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I found the solution.

I found help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-a-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-six-digit-code-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954792/gtk3-and-python-rgba-convert-to-hex), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030473/how-to-set-colors-for-nodes-in-networkx-python).

I changed the elif statement to use the new function I modified: `convert_to_hex`, and I put the output into the color_map - and it works as expected.

```
def convert_to_hex(rgba_color) :
    red = int(rgba_color[0]*255)
    green = int(rgba_color[1]*255)
    blue = int(rgba_color[2]*255)
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (red, green, blue)

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

color_map = []
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greens')

for node in g:
    if node in list_1:
        color_map.append('yellow')
    elif node in list_2:
        rgba = cmap(dict_1[node])
        color_map.append(convert_to_hex(rgba))


nx.draw(g, node_color = color_map, node_size = 75)
```